# How to autoreconnect a Bluetooth keychain connected on my iOS app then restart my iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, state-restoration

I have an objective c application that implements coreBluetooth framework to connect with Bluetooth keychains. All is correct, I connect with Bluetooth keychain, if I go to background my device keep connected. If my device is powered off or lost then is reconnect..  And my application detect when I do click in the button Bluetooth keychain with service and with the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic. So all this is correct.

But I'm trying use restoration properties with willRestoreState function, and this not work... I send my application to background, but when I reboot my iPhone, this isn't reconnecting and not works didUpdateValueForCharacteristic.

I have added the centralManager and all functions Bluetooth delegate to AppDelegate with the functions to restore application and I use a custom queue to connect centralManager Bluetooth. But I don't know what is the problem and why not reconnect then reboot.

```
    @interface AppDelegate ()
    
    @property (strong,nonatomic) CBCentralManager *central;
    @property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *targetPeripheral;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *discoveredPeripherals;
    
    @property (strong,nonatomic) CBPeripheral *connectedPeripheral;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) CBUUID *deviceInfoUUID;
    @end

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        ViewController *myloginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"]; 
            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myloginController];
            self.window.rootViewController = navController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
        self.discoveredPeripherals=[NSMutableArray new];
        self.deviceInfoUUID=[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFE0"];

    //I have added this code to connect then reboot iPhone:
    NSArray *centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];
    if ((centralManagerIdentifiers) && (centralManagerIdentifiers.count > 0)) {
        // The system knows about one or more centrals that need to be restored.
        for (NSString *identifier in centralManagerIdentifiers) {
            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myco.cm", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
            self.central = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:queue options:@{CBPeripheralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey : identifier,CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:@YES}];
            [self.referencesToCentrals addObject:self.central];
        }
    }
    else {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myco.cm", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        self.central = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:queue options:@{CBPeripheralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey : @"1C7757658-D187-99D2-9578-7B0976AAAEB4",CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:@YES }];
        [self.referencesToCentrals addObject:self.central];
    }
       
    //An this is my willrestoreState function
    -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
            
        NSArray *peripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey];
        
        if ([peripherals count]>0) {                                                            // There are peripherals
            for (CBPeripheral* p in peripherals) {
                if ([p.identifier isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:self.UUID]]) {                // which are sensorTags
                    [self.central connectPeripheral:[peripherals firstObject] options:nil];          // so let's reconnect
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
        - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(nonnull CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(nullable NSError *)error {
            
            NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            
            NSLog(@"Receive from Peripheral: %@",content);
        }
    
        -(void) startScan {
            [self.central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFE0"]] options:nil];
        }
    
        - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
             NSLog(@"We are in background");
        }

        -(void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
        switch (central.state) {
            case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
                [self startScan];
                break;
            case CBManagerStateUnknown:
                break;
            case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
                break;
            case CBManagerStateResetting:
                break;
            case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
                break;
            case CBManagerStateUnauthorized:
                break;
        }
    }
    
    -(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
        
        if([self.central retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFE0"]]] != 0){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.nameBT = peripheral.name;
                self.UUID = peripheral.identifier.UUIDString;
            });
        }
        
        if (![self.discoveredPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.discoveredPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
            });
        }
        
            if (self.connectedPeripheral) {
                [self.central cancelPeripheralConnection:self.connectedPeripheral];
            }
            self.targetPeripheral=peripheral.identifier.UUIDString;
            [self.central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
        
    }

    -(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
        self.connectedPeripheral=peripheral;
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.nameBT = peripheral.name;
            self.UUID = peripheral.identifier.UUIDString;
        });
        
        peripheral.delegate=self;
        [peripheral discoverServices:@[self.deviceInfoUUID]];
    }
    
    And I have added this to try if application reconnect bluetooth:
    
        -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder {
            return YES;
        }

    -(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"Disconnected from peripheral");
    if ([self.targetPeripheral isEqualToString:peripheral.identifier.UUIDString]) {
            NSLog(@"Retrying");
            [self.central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

How can I reconnect when iPhone reboot automatically without need open application?
What am I doing wrong?